# Variables doesn't compare properly

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, toad

**Problem**: why my `decode` statement does not return the value I need?

The first thing I noticed it was the date format was wrong because toad was assigning it in `DD/MM/RR` and im trying to compare it with `DD/MM/YYY`. So I tried to set the `nls` format at the beginning of the procedure.

Can I have an advice on how to solve this problem?

Kindly find the code below

```
 declare

    vMES_ACTUAL                                         NUMBER(6);
    vMES_ANT                                            NUMBER(6);
    vTRIM_ANT                                           NUMBER(6);
    vTRIM_ACT                                           NUMBER(6);
    vMES_BASE                                           NUMBER(6);
    vMES_INTA                                           NUMBER(6);
    vMES_ULT_DIC                                        NUMBER(6);
    vFECHA                                              DATE;
    vMES_CURSO                                          NUMBER(6);
    ----------
    vFECHA1         DATE;
    vFECHA2         DATE;
    vFECHA3         DATE;
    vFECHA4         DATE;
    vFECHA5         DATE;
    vFECHA6         DATE;
    vNUM_DIAS_CARGA NUMBER;
    vSEMANAS_TRANSC NUMBER;
    var_mes1 number(6);
    var_mes2 number(6);
    var_mes3 number(6);
    ----------
    FEC_VAR_DIA      VARCHAR2(10);

    Pmes number(6):=201810;

    begin

    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format = ''DD/MM/YYYY''';



       SELECT Pmes INTO vMES_CURSO FROM DUAL;

        /* Ultimos 6 dias de carga */

       SELECT MAX(ID_FECHA) INTO vFECHA1
        FROM CAP_BPP_FECHA_VAR6DIAS;

      SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_FECHA),vFECHA1) INTO vFECHA2
        FROM CAP_BPP_FECHA_VAR6DIAS
        WHERE ID_FECHA < vFECHA1;

      SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_FECHA),vFECHA2) INTO vFECHA3
       FROM CAP_BPP_FECHA_VAR6DIAS
       WHERE ID_FECHA < vFECHA2;

     SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_FECHA),vFECHA3) INTO vFECHA4
       FROM CAP_BPP_FECHA_VAR6DIAS
       WHERE ID_FECHA < vFECHA3;

   SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_FECHA),vFECHA4) INTO vFECHA5
     FROM CAP_BPP_FECHA_VAR6DIAS
    WHERE ID_FECHA < vFECHA4;

     SELECT NVL(MAX(ID_FECHA),vFECHA5) INTO vFECHA6
       FROM CAP_BPP_FECHA_VAR6DIAS
       WHERE ID_FECHA < vFECHA5;

      /* Hace el conteo de los numeros de dias */
     SELECT COUNT(*)
       INTO vNUM_DIAS_CARGA
     FROM CAP_BPP_FECHA_VAR6DIAS;


    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('TRUNCATE TABLE CAP_BPP_CTA_VAR_PASO');



 INSERT /*+  NOLOGGING */ INTO CAP_BPP_CTA_VAR6DIAS_PASO(
              ID_CLIENTE, ID_CONTRATO, ID_MES, ID_PRODUCTO, ID_SUBPRODUCTO, 
              ID_DIVISA,
              SDO_PUNT_DIA_1)
              SDO_PUNT_DIA_2,
              SDO_PUNT_DIA_3,
              SDO_PUNT_DIA_4,
              SDO_PUNT_DIA_5,
              SDO_PUNT_DIA_6)
    SELECT BT.ID_CLIENTE, BT.ID_CONTRATO, vMES_CURSO, BT.ID_PRODUCTO, 
    BT.ID_SUBPRODUCTO,BT.ID_DIVISA,
              CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 1 THEN 0 ELSE NVL(SUM(DECODE(TO_DATE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,'DD/MM/YYYY'),vFECHA1,SDO_PUNTUAL)),0) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_1
              CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 2 THEN 0 ELSE NVL(SUM(DECODE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,vFECHA2,SDO_PUNTUAL)),0) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_2,
              CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 3 THEN 0 ELSE NVL(SUM(DECODE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,vFECHA3,SDO_PUNTUAL)),0) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_3,
              CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 4 THEN 0 ELSE NVL(SUM(DECODE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,vFECHA4,SDO_PUNTUAL)),0) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_4,
              CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 5 THEN 0 ELSE NVL(SUM(DECODE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,vFECHA5,SDO_PUNTUAL)),0) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_5,
              CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 6 THEN 0 ELSE NVL(SUM(DECODE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,vFECHA6,SDO_PUNTUAL)),0) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_6
         FROM CAP_BPP_CTA_FTE_DIA BT
         WHERE BT.FECHA_INFORMACION IN (vFECHA1, vFECHA2, vFECHA3, vFECHA4, vFECHA5, vFECHA6)    
         GROUP BY ID_CLIENTE, ID_CONTRATO, vMES_CURSO, ID_PRODUCTO, BT.ID_SUBPRODUCTO, ID_DIVISA;)

       COMMIT;



end;
```

Comment: What is expected value , and what is the actual?  `Why my decode statement does not return the value i need?`

Comment: Why are you doing `TO_DATE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,'DD/MM/YYYY')` - that column is already a date, isn't it? It also looks odd for the decodes to have no default (i.e. 4th argument), so they end up null, and the sums are null, I think? It's hard to follow what is actually wrong from your description though.

Comment: @shareef, youre right the value i except its the sum of various amounts and im getting null

Comment: @AlexPoole i tried that to_date to see if there was the problem, i was trying to chek every possibility, the sum returns null but it shouldnt be null because the column im trying to sum does have values

Comment: Do the `FECHA_INFORMACION` dates have times other than midnight? What about `ID_FECHA` in `CAP_BPP_FECHA_VAR6DIAS`?

Comment: By the way, there is no such hint as `/*+ NOLOGGING */` so that will have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently doing this:

```
NVL(SUM(DECODE(TO_DATE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,'DD/MM/YYYY'),vFECHA1,SDO_PUNTUAL)),0)
```

which as discussed in comments should not be applying `TO_DATE()` to something that is already a date, so you either need:

```
NVL(SUM(DECODE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,vFECHA1,SDO_PUNTUAL)),0)
```

as you are doing for the comparisons, or if the `FECHA_INFORMACION` has values with time portions other than midnight:

```
NVL(SUM(DECODE(TRUNC(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION),vFECHA1,SDO_PUNTUAL)),0)
```

The `TRUNC()` function sets the time portion of a date value to midnight by default, so all values for a day get the same datetime value. If `ID_FECHA` also has non-midnight times then you can truncate those variables too, though from contact that seems less liekly to be the case:

```
NVL(SUM(DECODE(TRUNC(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION),TRUNC(vFECHA1),SDO_PUNTUAL)),0)
```

You could also default to zero in the decode, but it shouldn't make much difference in this case.

---

Without the `TO_DATE()` and its implicit `TO_CHAR()` the NLS settings don't matter, as you're comparing dates with other dates. Oracle uses an internal representation which has little to do with how your client displays dates as strings.

---

You probably also have a problem with this:

```
WHERE BT.FECHA_INFORMACION IN (vFECHA1, vFECHA2, vFECHA3, vFECHA4, vFECHA5, vFECHA6)
```

as that will only match exactly midnight too. You could truncate that too:

```
WHERE TRUNC(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION) IN (vFECHA1, vFECHA2, vFECHA3, vFECHA4, vFECHA5, vFECHA6)
```

again assuming `FECHA_INFORMACION` has non-midnight times and the variables are all at midnight. That would prevent on `FECHA_INFORMACION` being used, but you can switch to compare multiple ranges instead. See if that fixes the problem first.

Comment: Pool i tried both of the code you put, but im still recieving null

Comment: @CopyrightMan - your `where` clause is probably an issue too, I added that to my answer.

Comment: Pool i still recievieng null instead of a value, the issue here is that for example Fecha_informacion = '24/10/2018' and the value that takes vFecha1 = '24/10/18' hence decode returns null, and i dont know how to fix that vFecha1 issue

Comment: @CopyrightMan cant you provide us with `sub set dummy dump` to solve this once and for all ? and exact version of your oracle ( its related to how it works i had similar issues how sql planner understands and treats the query)

Comment: @CopyrightMan - dates don't have intrinsic formats. Seeing dates reported as different string formats implies at least one of them might not really be a date. So what data types are the two columns involved?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem the easiest way, maybe my question was wrongly formulated because i only wanted to match the date format to get data from the query. Thanks to the guys that tried to help.  This is the way i solved it.

```
INSERT /*+  NOLOGGING */ INTO CAP_BPP_CTA_VAR6DIAS_PASO(
          ID_CLIENTE, ID_CONTRATO, ID_MES, ID_PRODUCTO, ID_SUBPRODUCTO, ID_DIVISA,
          SDO_PUNT_DIA_1,
          SDO_PUNT_DIA_2,
          SDO_PUNT_DIA_3,
          SDO_PUNT_DIA_4,
          SDO_PUNT_DIA_5,
          SDO_PUNT_DIA_6)
   SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(BT,4) */
          ID_CLIENTE, ID_CONTRATO, vMES_CURSO, ID_PRODUCTO, BT.ID_SUBPRODUCTO,ID_DIVISA,
          CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 1 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(DECODE(TO_DATE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,'DD/MM/RR'),vFECHA1,SDO_PUNTUAL)) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_1,
          CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 2 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(DECODE(TO_DATE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,'DD/MM/RR'),vFECHA2,SDO_PUNTUAL)) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_2,
          CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 3 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(DECODE(TO_DATE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,'DD/MM/RR'),vFECHA3,SDO_PUNTUAL)) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_3,
          CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 4 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(DECODE(TO_DATE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,'DD/MM/RR'),vFECHA4,SDO_PUNTUAL)) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_4,
          CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 5 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(DECODE(TO_DATE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,'DD/MM/RR'),vFECHA5,SDO_PUNTUAL)) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_5,
          CASE WHEN vNUM_DIAS_CARGA < 6 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(DECODE(TO_DATE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,'DD/MM/RR'),vFECHA6,SDO_PUNTUAL)) END SDO_PUNT_DIA_6
     FROM CAP_BPP_CTA_FTE_DIA BT
     WHERE TO_DATE(BT.FECHA_INFORMACION,'DD/MM/RR') IN (vFECHA1, vFECHA2, vFECHA3, vFECHA4, vFECHA5, vFECHA6)    
     GROUP BY ID_CLIENTE, ID_CONTRATO, vMES_CURSO, ID_PRODUCTO, BT.ID_SUBPRODUCTO, ID_DIVISA;

   COMMIT;
```